# PFUser refreshWithKey?

Tags: parse-platform

So I have my `currentUser`. There are some pointers in my user class that aren't included on first load. At some point later I need them.

I understand that I can just get the pointer from `currentUser` and then query for that object. However, I want that key INCLUDED/ATTACHED to the `currentUser` object so I can use it at this time and at later times.

I don't see any methods in the Parse docs for this. The only way I can imagine doing this is if I just run a separate `user` query, `includeKey` for the pointers I want to include, and then save this retrieved object as `currentUser`.

HOWEVER, I'm doing this a lot in my app and I'm wondering if there is some convenience method in the Parse API that I'm missing - something like a `refreshWithKey` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have pointers in your user class that are not available, you can use fetchIfNeeded on them:

```
PFObject *address = [PFUser currentUser][@"address"];
[address fetchIfNeeded];
```

Or with a block:

```
[address fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  NSString *street = address[@"street"];
}];
```

Comment: That creates a new `address` object, correct? If I query the `address` pointer in the `currentUser` object will it point to this newly fetched `address` object?

Comment: No, this does not create anything. This only works when you have pointers to other objects (i.e. an Address object), that is not fetched together with the object containing the pointer. If your user class has a pointer to Address, you can fetch this object if you don't have it already using fetchIfNeeded. No need to query.

Comment: It will perform a check for isDataAvailable in the background and only perform the fetch if it has not yet been fetched. The next time you need this, isDataAvailable will return YES and the fetch will not be performed, so there is little overhead calling this repeatedly.

Comment: OK, just to be super clear, if I do `[address fetchIfNeeded];` as written in your answer, then the next time I try to access `[PFUser currentUser][@"address"];`, then it will be there in the user object?

Comment: In the same session, yes